# Symfony2 - how to assign Doctrine Entity as Route resource?

Tags: symfony

I want to dynamically change my routes based on settings was stored in database, how I can do this in Symfony2?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [this bundle](http://bundles.knplabs.org/symfony-cmf/ChainRoutingBundle) to replace Symfony default routing system to a dynamic one.

Comment: @ebaranov Welcome. You can also mark my answer as accepted by clicking a tick to the left of the answer.